# Cassandra: inserting timeuuid error

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I have following table

```
create table test(
         userId varchar,
         notifId timeuuid,
         notification varchar,
         time bigint,read boolean,
         primary key(userId, notifId)) with clustering order by (notifId desc);
```

I am running following query:

```
PreparedStatement   pstmt  = session.prepare("INSERT INTO notifications(userId, notifId, notification, time, read) VALUES(?, now(), ?, ?, ?)");

BoundStatement      boundStatement  = new BoundStatement(pstmt);
        session.execute(boundStatement.bind("123", "hello", new Date().getTime(), false));
```

I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Type error: cannot assign result of function now (type timeuuid) to notifid (type 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ReversedType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType)')
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.extractCause(ResultSetFuture.java:277)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.toPreparedStatement(Session.java:281)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.prepare(Session.java:172)
    at com.example.cassandra.SimpleClient.loadData(SimpleClient.java:130)
    at com.example.cassandra.SimpleClient.main(SimpleClient.java:214)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Type error: cannot assign result of function now (type timeuuid) to notifid (type 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ReversedType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType)')
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.convertException(ResultSetFuture.java:307)
```

I am using cassandra 1.2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should insert the timeuuid generated via datastax driver. In your case , since you are using version 1 timeuuid, you must use

> UUIDs.timeBased()

You can find the above in following reference

http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html

Comment: and path to this class is `import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug (similar or the same as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5472) , and you're using pretty old version of Cassandra. I recommend you to upgrade to the latest 1.2.x release, retest your scenario and file an issue, if the problem still persists