# Error when starting cassandra server

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After system restart, cassandra server doesn't start and give this error:

```
org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Unknown timeuuid representation: W
```

This the stacktrace:

```
ERROR [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:1] 2017-09-04 19:02:11,277 CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread Thread[PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:1,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Unknown timeuuid representation: W
at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType.fromString(TimeUUIDType.java:102) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer.hasNext(StandardAnalyzer.java:168) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.disk.PerSSTableIndexWriter$Index.add(PerSSTableIndexWriter.java:208) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.disk.PerSSTableIndexWriter.lambda$nextUnfilteredCluster$0(PerSSTableIndexWriter.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
```

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191933/cassandra-inserting-timeuuid-error

Comment: Did C* safely shutdown before it was restarted?